# No package 'libcrypto' found in mac

Tags: macos, c++11, openssl, libcrypto

I have a question regarding openssl lib. I am running cmake command and I see this error: No package 'libcrypto' found. Would you please help?

```
-- Checking for module 'libcrypto'
--   No package 'libcrypto' found
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:458 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:637 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  PlaylistParser/src/CMakeLists.txt:2 (pkg_check_modules)
```

Here is my openssl list:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/.bottle/etc/ (8 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/bin/c_rehash
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/bin/openssl
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/include/openssl/ (75 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/lib/engines/ (12 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/lib/pkgconfig/ (3 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/lib/ (4 other files)
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/share/man/ (1683 files)
```

Comment: Is this link issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to have openssl first in your PATH run:
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find openssl you may need to set:
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"

For pkg-config to find openssl you may need to set:
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig"

the path
`/usr/local/opt/openssl`
may be
`/usr/local/opt/openssl@3.1` etc.

Comment: I installed with `brew` and the library was in `/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have issue with the paths
https://github.com/scipr-lab/libsnark/issues/99

try this out might be helpful